# Export ARSCNFaceGeometry wrapped in MDLAsset fail on iOS 14 with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I have an application that exploits ARKit's face tracking feature to build .obj face model files. It generally follows practices in [Tracking and visualizing faces](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/tracking_and_visualizing_faces). The app gets the anchor in `func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor)`, and update the geometry in `func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor)`.

For the face model export, the following function is used, which wraps the `ARSCNFaceGeometry` in a `MDLAsset` and export the asset. The code is as follows.

```swift
func exportMesh(_ geometry: SCNGeometry, to url: URL, completion: (() -> ())?) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let mesh = MDLMesh(scnGeometry: geometry)
        let asset = MDLAsset()
        asset.add(mesh)
        do {
            try asset.export(to: url)
        } catch {
            print("Can't write mesh to url")
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion?()
        }
    }
}
```

The application works fine before on iOS 13. However, when I installed it on iOS 14, the app crashes on the line `try asset.export`. The do-catch syntax did not catch the error, it directly crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I tried to export only a `SCNBox` in this step and it worked fine, seems it has something to do with the `ARSCNFaceGeometry`.

My Mac and the test device are all updated to the newest system, the test device is an iPhone X.

A screen shot may be helpful.

[image: screenshot]

I would be so appreciate if you could provide some hint.

Comment: Can you print out `asset`, `url`, and `mesh` to make sure they are not null? Can you take a screenshot of the full stack trace when the exception is reached in the debugger?

Comment: @jtbandes Thanks. I just verified that `asset`, `url` and `mesh` are not null, screen shot added to the problem. But I don't think there is anything useful in the debugger's prints.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm a bit late but I ran into a similar crash when exporting SCNGeometry. The last callstack frame '_platform_strlen' led me to something string-related. So in my case I just assigned a name to each material referenced by the SCNGeometry instance.